# "Cloning" a program from a CentOS 7 machine to another

Tags: centos, centos7, lyx

I am in need of working with a specific version of the text editor Lyx, the 1.3.3, on a CentOS 7 environment. I found the .rpm package and some sort of source code, but as it's a very old software, many library are obsolete and cannot be found when installing from the rpm file and for some reasons no c++ compiler I used seems to be good to compile the source code.

Now my question: I do have a CentOS virtual machine with this specific version of Lyx installed properly. Is there a way to "clone" or somehow copy it into my CentOS main partition? Or, if this is too barbaric, how can I extract/install from the VM CentOS the libraries I need?

I apologize if my question doesn't make much sense, I am by no means an expert of Linux distros and I might have some misconceptions brought over from Windows.

Comment: Interesting question, +1. On your CentOS machine can you *compile* LyX? If so, perhaps it is easier if you compile statically (i.e., all the libraries are in the binary at the cost of a possibly huge binary size)? I'm also very curious, why do you need that specific version of LyX? By the way, welcome to (asking questions on) Stack Overflow!

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I am not able to compile that particular version of LyX, as it is a version no longer supported by the autoconfig/configure scripts, and trying to set up all the dependencies manually brings me back to the starting point, i.e. that the correct files are outdated and impossible to find.
I need this particular version due to compatibility issues, probably with older machines, used by my colleagues - it's some sort of "ipse dixit" on which i need to adapt if i don't want to use a virtual machine

Comment: I see. I don't have many ideas. Note that later LyX versions can import 1.3.x .lyx files, and also export to 1.3.x .lyx files.

Comment: Thank you anyway for the suggestions, i'll continue my quest for the obsolete lyx!

Comment: You might want to ask on the mailing list "lyx-users" which is active and mostly friendly :)